# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want to import date value from excel cell. cell value having "10 October 2013" format. I want to convert it to datetime data type. My code getting error "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

//code

```
      OleDbCommand olecmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", olecon);


               OleDbDataReader olerdr = olecmd.ExecuteReader();
                 while (olerdr.Read())
                 {
                    deldate = olerdr.GetValue(13).ToString();
                     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["irisdb"].ConnectionString))
                     {
                         con.Open();
                         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procdamandrugs", con);
                         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(deldate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//getting error in this line
                         SqlParameter par9 = new SqlParameter();
                         par9.ParameterName = "@deleffdate";
                         par9.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
                         par9.Value = dt;
                         cmd.Parameters.Add(par9);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    }
```

Do any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the utilizing the DateTime.TryParse method before constructing your SQL objects.  Ensure you have quality input before having a conversation with your database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Below is a sample from my own code for an asp.net application

```
    // Validation
    DateTime dtOut_StartDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out dtOut_StartDate))
    {
        Message = "Start date is not a valid format.";
        txtStartDate.CssClass = ErrorCssClass.TextBox;
        txtStartDate.Focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> cell value having "10 October 2013" format.

You are giving wrong format in ParseExact that does not match with the date string you are passing. You need different format than you gave. For day you need `dd`, for month you need `MMMM` and for year you need `yyyy` and you have to give spaces as separator.

It is worth the article [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for using the string formats for date conversion.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(deldate, "dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I want to insert it to sql database in "MM-dd-yyyy".. I also tried the  code given above. Still having the same error.

Comment: On which line you getting error, check the database procedure argument / column format if it comes from database

Answer (score 0):

**Select Date Time setting from Right lower bottom & Change the format from here......**

[image]