# String Conversation to DateTime

Tags: c#-4.0

i am facing a problem while converting string to DateTime.It gives me "string was not recognized as a valid datetime" exception.

**Here is my input string**

```
10/28/2014 3:13:12 AM"
```

**Code Snippet**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/28/2014 3:13:12 AM", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have gone through couple of stack overflow posts but still having same issue.

**Reference Post**
**[String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in C# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934089/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-in-c-sharp-asp-net)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this format string: `"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/28/2014 3:13:12 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to convert the resulting `DateTime` back to a stering with this format: `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm`:

```
string result = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` forces english month names instead of the localized name.

Comment: Thanks but i have to covert it into "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" format

Answer (score 0):

You are missing both seconds (ss) and the AM/PM designation (tt). Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for the various designations and how they're interpreted in this conversion.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10/28/2014 3:13:12 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Without these, it doesn't know how to interpret the extra data you passed it.

This will assign `dt` the value `10/28/2014 3:13:12 AM`

Comment: Still getting "{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}"

Comment: @user3751544 This works correctly for me. Can you check that your format (`MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`) matches mine exactly?